# Angular Js $Resource issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am having the below in my factory

```
var MyResource = function($resource){
var MyResources  =  $resource('/test/rest/tests/activities/:userId',
  {
    userId: '@userId'
  },
  {
     query: {isArray: false}
  }
  );
  return MyResources ;
};
```

And I am calling the method like

```
MyResource.get({userid:$stateParams.userId})
    .$promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.week1 = data.total1;
            $scope.total1 = data.totalAll1;
            monthArray = data.tasksMonth;
            console.log(monthArray);
            init();
  });
```

If the value of `$stateParams.userId` is testUser, I want the url like below

```
/test/rest/tests/activities/testUser
```

But now am getting a url like below

```
/test/rest/tests/activities?userId=testUser
```

Comment: This is javascript not java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects in Javascript are case sensitive, your are using:

```
MyResource.get({userid:$stateParams.userId})
```

Instead of :

```
MyResource.get({userId:$stateParams.userId})
```

Where the userId change from **userid** to **userId** (**I** is in uppercase)